# JSON field names, changing them on output

Tags: json, jackson

I have a json which i map to an object as follows:

original json:

```
      {
        "amount_predicted" : 1.34
      }
```

mapped:

```
public class Amount {
    @JsonProperty("amount_predicted")
    private BigDecimal amountPredicted;

}
```

I do some work and check this amount and then send this to the client. The issue i have is i want the name of the field to be camelcase on output. But since i already use the json property it wont do that.

This is what id like:

```
{
   "amountPredicted" : 1.34
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate the getter and the setter of the `amountPredicted` field in the `Amount` class respectively with `@JsonProperty("amount_predicted")` and `@JsonProperty("amountPredicted")` annotations thus differentiating the property's name in the deserialization process from the one used for the serialization:

```
public class Amount {

    private BigDecimal amountPredicted;

    @JsonProperty("amount_predicted")
    public void setAmountPredicted(BigDecimal amountPredicted) {
        this.amountPredicted = amountPredicted;
    }

    @JsonProperty("amountPredicted")
    public BigDecimal getAmountPredicted() {
        return amountPredicted;
    }
}

Amount amount = mapper.readValue(json, Amount.class);
//it will print {"amountPredicted":1.34}
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(amount));
```

**EDIT:** as pointed out by [@user1555190](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1555190/user1555190) is much simpler to use the [`JsonAlias`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html) annotation:

```
public class Amount {
    @JsonAlias(value = {"amount_predicted"})
    private BigDecimal amountPredicted;
}
```

Comment: could also use @JsonAlias

Comment: @user1555190 Absolutely correct, added your observation to the answer.